# SQL command from variable in SSIS Dataflow task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

An existing SSIS package has Data source with Data access mode: SQL command from variable. User variable is having select statement as value. Now I added a column to select statement in variable and saved the package. This new column is not showing up in data source columns list. Tried closing the package and reopening it, on doing this I no longer see the new column in variable value select statement too. Looking for solutions other than creating a new variable and calling it in data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Variable. Right click on it and select Properties.

In the Properties window, you will see `EvaluateAsExpression` is equal to True. Click the `Expression` box and then the ellipses/triple dots/.... In *there* you will need to add the column as part of the string that is being built

[image]